# Would I be able to use an eGPU on unsupported Macs with an AMD Pascal graphics card?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra, gpu

I want to be able to Metal 2 (for eGPU support) on my MacBook Pro 2011 13" but my Mac isn't on the supported list (2012+). I know that Metal doesn't depend on the CPU. I'm wondering whether Apple bases Metal support on the GPU you are currently running or if they completely block 2011 and older Macs from using Metal. I'm interested in running a RX580 which is compatible with Metal on an eGPU (I know I can't run an eGPU out of the box I would use the eGPU script from eGPU.io)

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I hope you don't mind me saying, but it's a little unclear what you're ultimately wanting to achieve? This isn't always necessary, but in this case your question seems a little confused and I'd hate for you to take action on the basis of someone's answer when what you're really wanting to do may not be possible. Allow me to clarify...

Comment: ...Your question title asks a specific question, but then the question body touches upon a number of things, but it's not clear *how* you want to use Metal? I'm asking because your assumption that Metal depends on the OpenGL version makes no sense. Metal and OpenGL are two very distinct APIs, one does not depend on the other. Perhaps you could [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/325578/edit) your question to provide more details or to clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it to more reflect what I'm asking